# Can I ignore Jinja2's "UndefinedError" during tests?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I'm using Flask with Flask-WTF. I've decided to disable CSRF protection in tests, since testing with it is kinda awkward, and I don't want to test Flask/Flask-WTF. However, this raises another problem:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'trip_planner.auth.forms.LoginForm object' has no attribute 'csrf_token'
```

The offending template is as follows:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block main %}
    <form method="POST">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        <div>
            {{ form.username.label }}{{ form.username }}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ form.password.label }}{{ form.password }}
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

My understanding is as follows: if CSRF is disabled completely, WTForms doesn't bother to inject a CSRF token field into the form.

Can I make Jinja ignore this error or avoid this issue otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more reading, I believe I found a solution.

Replacing `form.csrf_token` with [`form.hidden_tag`](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#flask_wtf.FlaskForm.hidden_tag) would render the CSRF field if it's present without depending on the field name.